# Compare two strings and remove common elements

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have two comma seperated `NSString`'s & I want to remove the similar characters from first string only.

```
ex. str1 = 0,1,2,3
    str2 = 1,2.
    output -> str1 = 0,3 and str2 = 1,2.
```

I have one option that, seperate both the string with comma seperated values in a array. But it requires two `NSArray`'s & apply `loop` and then remove the common elements, but it is very tedious job. 
So I want some simple & proper solution which avoid the looping.

kindly help me to sort out this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this one:

No loop is required!!!

You have got all the required APIs.

```
NSString *str1=@"0,1,2,3";
NSString *str2=@"1,2";

NSMutableArray *arr1=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[str1 componentsSeparatedByString:@","]];

[arr1 removeObjectsInArray:[str2 componentsSeparatedByString:@","]];
NSLog(@"arr1 %@",arr1);
/*
NSMutableString *finalString=[NSMutableString new];

for (NSInteger i=0; i<[arr1 count]; i++) {
    NSString *str=[arr1 objectAtIndex:i];

    [finalString appendString:str];
    if (i!=[arr1 count]-1) {
      [finalString appendString:@","];  
    }
}
*/
NSString *finalString=[arr1 componentsJoinedByString:@","];
NSLog(@"finalString %@",finalString);
```

Comment: +1 if you are happy with the default isEqual implementation of strings, this is shortest

Comment: -1 Casting NSArray to NSMutableArray will crash when you remove objects from immutable array. Please change that then I'll +1

Comment: The (very strange) thing is that `componentsSeparatedByString` in fact returns an instance of `NSMutableArray`, so that this code actually does not crash. But of course one should not rely on that.

Comment: @Anoop, thanks for your, it works fine for me but it returns me the array & I want the comma seperated string. Can u plz modify your code.

Comment: @InderKumarRathore: changed.

Comment: @Girish: changed as per you requirement.

Comment: As you can see, in comments the ',' is used to append but as i said no loop is required, a vast range of API is there compoJoinedBystr:

Comment: @3d0: that is alrdy solvd.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya sorry, didn't notice, going to delete my answer. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Something like that ?

```
 NSString *string = @"0,1,2,3";
 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self like '1' OR self like '2'"];
 NSLog(@"%@",[[string componentsSeparatedByString:@","] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]);
```

Comment: But the elements are dynamic.

Comment: it shouldnt be a static predicate but a predicate is the right way IMHO -- it avoids a manual for loop

Answer (score 0):

```
    id str1=@"aa,ab,ac,cd,ce,cf";
    id str2=@"aa,ac,cd,cf";
    //no ab and no ce

    id cmps1 = [str1 componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    id cmps2 = [str2 componentsSeparatedByString:@","];        

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT SELF IN %@", cmps2];
    NSArray *final = [cmps1 filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]; 
    id str = [final componentsJoinedByString:@","];
    NSLog(@"%@", str);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that I can think of would be this:

```
NSMutableArray* arr1 = [str1 componentsSeparatedByString:@","] mutableCopy];
NSArray* arr2 = [str2 componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
for (NSString* str in arr2) {
  [arr1 removeObject:str];
}
NSString* newString1 = [arr1 componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```

Is this what you tried? If "str1" looks something like "1,1,2,2,2", then you might have some more work to do here to get rid of the duplicates. But that's basically it.